# message sent to deallocated instance ! cant find error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release-management

alright I am looking for this error since 2 hours and I just cant figure it out please help me.
I have the following situation I have 2 viewcontroller.
one presents the other one as modalview like that.

```
SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc]init];
[searchViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
searchViewController.delegate = self;
searchViewController.senderTag = [sender tag];
[self presentModalViewController:searchViewController animated:YES];
[searchViewController release];
```

in my searchviewcontroller I do this in the .h file

```
BSKmlResult *selectedAirport;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BSKmlResult *selectedAirport;
```

in the .m file i synthesize it and then set it like that

```
selectedAirport = [self.airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and then release it here

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [selectedAirport release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

in the delegate methode of my SearchViewController which is implemented in the first
viewcontroller where I also present the SearchViewController
i have the following

```
if (controller.selectedAirport) {
            if (departureAirport) {
                [departureAirport release];
            }

        departureAirport = [controller.selectedAirport copy];
}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I narrowed down where the error happens it is in the dealloc of my SearchViewController
    [selectedAirport release];

but I cant figure out where my mistake is 
please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
selectedAirport = [self.airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You arent retaining selectedAirport here.

Change it to

```
self.selectedAirport = [self.airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Since you couldnt find it out, probably you dont know this...

If you dont access member variables by self.memberVariable, you are not accessing its property. Thus, it was not getting retained.

Ofcourse you can also retain it by saying

```
selectedAirport = [[self.airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
```

But whats the use of your property then...

Comment: your are perfectly correct! changed it to self.selectedAirport and it works like charm! I did rely not know this, I am fairly new to all this. One more question when do I use self. and when not ? is there a rule ? ore do I always use self. ?

Comment: @bllubbor - I always use self and have never had any problems.

Comment: Its simple, use self whenever you want to access the property. But i personally use self to "set" and dont to "get".

Comment: When you use self.property, what you're doing is calling the setter function for the property, which does more than simply property=value.  Property=value just sets the variable to a given value, while the setter can also handle things like retain / release.  (Similar functionality can theoretically exist for getters, but I don't know of any case where that is relevant)

Comment: @RonLugge thanks for clearing that up now its clear ;) @pratikshabhisikar sounds very reasonable after RonLugges explanation thank you both helped me a lot

Answer (score 3):

You need to use self. to run it through the synthesized method, to get the retain.

```
 self.selectedAirport = [self.airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is quite old but just wanted to add something useful to it. In the above case the member variable name and property name are identical so you may still by mistake set the value of member variable instead accessing it using property that will call retain implicitly. Hence the best way to make sure you always use self.selectedAirport is to name the member variable something different than your property.

For example, in .h file you can have below implementation:

```
NSString *_selectedAirport;
```

then encapsulate it inside a property like below

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *selectedAirport;
```

and in .m implementation file synthesize it like below:

```
@synthesize selectedAirport = _selectedAirport;
```

By doing above, if you try to access it like below

```
selectedAirport = [self.airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

then it would result in an error and you will be prompted to use self.selectedAirport.

Also in this case your dealloc method can have either

```
self.selectedAirport = nil;
```

or

```
[_selectedAirport release];
```